# Observing LiveData in ViewModel best practices

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel, android-livedata

I'm seeking the best way to observe data in `ViewModel`.

I'm using MVVM + DataBinding.

**Repository:**

```
private val data = MutableLiveData<String>()

suspend fun getData(): LiveData<String> {
        return withContext(IO) {
            val response = apiRequest { api.getData() }
            data.postValue(response)
            data
        }
    }
```

It requests data from server and returns a live data. ViewModel must observe the data changes.

**ViewModel:**

```
    suspend fun getData() {
        val data = repository.getData()
        MediatorLiveData<String>().apply {
            addSource(data) {
                gotData(it)
                removeSource(data)
            }
            observeForever { }
        }
    }

    private fun gotData(data: String) {
        //use data
    }
```

ViewModel uses a `MediatorLiveData` to observe changes of the `LiveData` that comes from repository. I've added the data as a source to observe changes and remove it after it triggers to prevent firing events multiple times when I get data multiple times. And there must be a fake observer to `MediatorLiveData` so the onChange method of the `MediatorLiveData` triggers.

Let's say that I just need the data to hide/show a view (or even fill data to my recyclerview's adaper). Then I just call the below code and use an Observable and DataBinding like this:

```
val adapter: ObservableField<DataAdapter> = ObservableField()
val recyclerviewVisibility: ObservableField<Int> = ObservableField(View.GONE)
...
...
recyclerviewVisibility.set(View.VISIBLE)
adapter.set(DataAdapter(dataList))
```

So I don't need to pass the data to `Fragment` or `Activity` to use the `viewLifecycleOwner`.
I also cannot use `observeForever` in `ViewModel` because it may fire onChange method multiple times in some situations.

Is there any better approach to get and observe data in `ViewModel`?

---

**Solution :**

I've found out that the best way to reach my goal is to get the data from repository without using `LiveData`:

**Repository**

```
suspend fun getData() : String{
    return  apiRequest { api.getData() }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
suspend fun getData(){
   val data = repository.getData()
    gotData(data)
}

fun gotData(data: String) {
    //use data
}
```

It's much simpler now.

---

**Bonus:**

extension:

```
fun <T : Any> ViewModel.request(request: suspend () -> (T), result: (T) -> (Unit) = {}) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        result(request())
    }
}
```

usage:

```
request({request.getData()}) {
    //use data
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I figured the problem right, I think you could use the `map` transformation on the `LiveData`.

Maybe it's better to change the repository code like the following:

```
private val reload = MutableLiveData<Unit>()

val data: LiveData<String> =
    reload.switchMap {
        liveData(IO) {
            emit(apiRequest { api.getData() })
        }
    }

fun reload() {
    reload.postValue(Unit) 
}
```

Then, in your `ViewModel` using map transtormation, you can intercept the emmited values:

```
val data: LiveData<String> = 
    repository.data.map {
        gotData(it)
        it
    }

fun reload() {
    repository.reload() 
}
```

Using this structure, you will be able to call ViewModel's `reload()` everytime you need to, leading to fetch fresh data from api and emitting it on the ViewModel's `data`.

Comment: `reload.switchMap` shows me 'Unresolved Reference' error. so `liveData(IO)` and `emit` also show the same error.

Comment: It's because of lacking dependency. Add `implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0'` in `build.gradle`.

Comment: Adding the dependency solved the errors but `reload.switchMap` and inner functions are not triggered.

Comment: Do you set an observer on ViewModel's `data`?

Comment: Setting the observer inside `ViewModel` is the main problem. Thats why I used `MediatorLiveData`, added a data source and removed it in my question. Using your answer I should add `data.observeForever{}` for all responses in `init` method of the viewmodel.

Comment: The question is why do you want to do that. The ViewModel's goal is to provide data to the view regarding the view's life-cycles. It doesn't seem right that you want to observe on a LiveData in ViewModel instead of observing it in view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217632/discussion-between-amir-and-aminography).